# what does this statement mean for expect or for bash?

Tags: bash, expect

Exploring expect page 219 :

```
#!/bin/bash
set kludge { ${1+"$@"}
shift
shift
exec expect -f $0 ${1+"$@"}
}
# rest of script follows
```

i am able to execute my expect script within this bash interpreter,even i can 
pass command line arguments like:
`./scriptname arg1 arg2 arg3` and so on
but when i tried
`sh -x ./scriptname arg1 arg2 arg3` it threw some error.
please clarify the above statements and does it really help to put expect scripts inside bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at it from Expect first, it's pretty simple. The [`set`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/set.htm) command, when given 2 arguments, sets the value of a variable. Here, the variable name is `kludge` and the value is the multi-line string between the `{braces}`. Note that in Tcl (and Expect) braces suppress expansion (variable substitution, command expansion, etc), in the same way that single quotes act in a shell. Assuming that the variable `kludge` is never used, this is a completely innocuous statement.

A bit trickier from the shell. The shell's [`set`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) command in this context will set the positional parameters. After this command:

```
$1 = "kludge"
$2 = "{"
$3, $4, ... <= will be the original command line parameters
```

Then there are 2 `shift` commands to pop `"kludge"` and `"{"` off the "stack" of parameters, restoring the original positional parameters. Then the `exec` command will launch expect, *replacing* the currently running shell process.
If `exec` was not used, expect would run and (presumably) terminate, and then the shell would report a syntax error on the next line: `}`

Overall, this is an overly clever way to launch an expect program. Replace everything before "# rest of script follows" with

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
```

Or if there's *much* more stuff happening in the shell portion, use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
do whatever shell initialization required
expect -c << 'END_OF_EXPECT'
# rest of expect script follows
# ...
END_OF_EXPECT
```

To pass options in this case:

```
expect - "$@" << 'END_OF_EXPECT'
# ...
```

The single `-` tells expect that commands will come on stdin.

Comment: thanks @glenn for the clear answer the secoand approch you mentioned is nice but can i pass positonal parameters to expect script in this case considering that it does not conflict with the bash schell script parameters... i mean can i do something like this expect -c parameter1 parameter2 << 'EOF'                               EOF